# How to define web fonts in SASS and LESS

Tags: css, sass, less

I am fairly new to SASS, I have used LESS for awhile but mainly just for variables and avoiding vendor prefixes. I usually define web fonts in CSS like this. Is it the same for SASS and LESS? It does not seem to work for me. In this example for testing I am setting all elements to the font Interstate.

```
/* Interstate font */
@font-face {
  font-family: Interstate;
  src: url(fonts/Interstate-Regular.otf);
}

* {
  font-family: 'Interstate' !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed single quotes for name and uri

```
/* Interstate font */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Interstate';
  src: url('fonts/Interstate-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting fix, but it still doesn't seem to work for me in SASS with your example

Comment: I've just been updating my answer.

Comment: It is quite strange, it should be working and I can see the font coming through in the CSS but it doesn't pick up the font, only if I have it in the CSS. I am using Ionic Mobile, so maybe something small is missing unrelated when compiled. Thanks for your help